# Swap/match "left" with "right" within a bracket block with regex

Tags: css, regex, replace

I'm trying to swap "left" with "right" and "right" with "left" so:

```
.left {
  left: 10px;
  float: right;
}
```

would be come:

```
.left {
  right: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

What kind of expression would match "left" or "right" but not ".left" only within brackets?

Comment: Is this for a once-off thing? Or are you trying to do this on arbitrary CSS?

Comment: Arbitrary CSS. A batch process on multiple CSS files.

Comment: Are you using a editor?

Comment: @user3587428 Did this help, or are you still having a problem with the question? Hey btw, I notice that you haven't yet voted on StackOverflow. If one of he answers solves your problem, please consider "accepting it" by clicking the checkmark on the left, as this is how the reputation system works (accepting an anwer gives reputation to both the answerer and to you). Of course there is no obligation to do so. Later when you have more reputation you can also upvote questions. Thanks for listening to my 20-second SO rep tutorial. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact syntax is heavily dependent on the language you're using to execute the regex, but [here's an example](http://regex101.com/r/eQ2cS6) using Python syntax.

The regex you'll find there looks like:

`/({[^}]*)left\s*:(.*?)}/s`

with a substitution expression of:

`\1right:\2}`

Comment: You should include your example in your answer (or at least the salient points of it).

Answer (score 1):

The following method works in .NET or PCRE (for instance PHP). In Python, use `\1\6\5\2\7` for the replacement instead of `$1$6$5$2$7`. Either of these replacement syntax will actually work in PCRE/PHP.

This method relies on a conditional and multiple capture groups. The reason this is more complex than TML's solution is that this method specifically makes sure that your string has either a right/left or left/right pattern, i.e., it will ignore left/left or right/right.

Search:

```
(?s)(\.(?:left|right)\s*{\W+)((left)|(right))(:.*?float:\s*)((?(3)right|left))(;.*?})
```

Replace:

```
$1$6$5$2$7
```